# Bulk delete contacts in Microsoft 365 Family edition

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I'm using Microsoft 365 Family edition, and the Outlook UI "Outlook (new)" has no way to bulk delete contacts nor to sync contacts with Google Contacts.

I made a mistake of using the contact import tool (after exporting and using Gmail's merge and fix),but didn't read the notes saying that the import (in Outlook) would not merge contacts, but simply **create new entries**! (I don't understand who ever would want that behavior, but nevermind for now).

I've searched the UI for ways to delete, and other than selecting 10 at a time, there seems to be no way. Further, the Graph API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts only returns 2 contacts (I have now 600+ contacts in my Outlook)

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

After long chain with MSFT support, they suggested this command - `olk.exe --clearLocalState` which completely resets Outlook-new, allowing for fresh import of contacts (and everything else)

Comment: Export, create Gmail account. Import to gmail. Use Merge and fix at contacts.google.com. Export from google (select the Outlook CSV format). Import to outlook. And yes I know this sounds like a joke but I am dead serious.

Comment: I did this. And I ended up with double the number of contacts in Outlook as I had before. The import to Outlook will create _new_ contacts. I'm looking for help in deleting existing contacts.

Comment: Haha. Yeah, of course you should delete all contacts before re-importing them. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: But that's the question. How do I do that?

Answer (score -3):

**Edit:** Please COMMENT why you are down voting my post before doing so. I yern for the opportunity to learn and can't improve without feedback

You can't do this directly but there is a workaround I discovered recently:

1. Export your contacts
2. Login to a gmail account
3. Import your export
4. Use the "Merge and Fix" feature on contacts.google.com (use the "Outlook CSV" option while exporting)
5. Export again
6. Upload the new export to outlook

Comment: You discovered it recently because I wrote it as a comment above?

Comment: Two people can independently discover functionality of major websites...

Comment: And yet, you did not. You just wrote out my comment as an answer.

Comment: Please cite your source on that one

Comment: The fact that you don't even know what you are talking about because you say the "Merge and Fix" feature has a "Outlook CSV" option but thats the export... Also the fact that you literally just wrote out my comment as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: On that we agree.

Comment: It seems like we agree

Comment: @Gantendo It is totally accurate to say I discovered it recently. I don't know why you disagree on that so much.

Comment: Of course you discovered it recently. Because I wrote it about 2 hours ago.

Comment: Comment war aside, this doesn't work b/c it will create _new_ contacts in Outlook

Comment: @ScottWeinstein I wish you had said something about this a little bit earlier...

Comment: It's in the original post

Comment: @ScottWeinstein I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: @ScottWeinstein just wondering if you found a solution? I'm having this problem now too